# Not able to locate element using java in selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I want to select a row and delete it,but id of row is dynamically generated so how can i access it using java in selenium webdriver. when i will add a row by using the application a new tr tag will be added with different id.so how can i select the row.Below is the html code for a table that has two rows with different id's.

```
<table id="SlotTable" class="noborder" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left"     
paging="false" style="border-top: 0px none; table-layout: fixed; width: 984px;">
<tbody id="tableBody">
<script>
<tr id="97.115.104.105.115.104" style="background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);">
<td width="254px" style="text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; width: 254px;">
<td width="110px" style="text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; width: 110px;">
<td width="60px" style="text-align: right; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; width: 60px;">
<td width="170px" style="text-align: right; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; width: 170px;">
<td width="100px" style="text-align: right; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; width: 100px;">
<td width="120px" style="text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; width: 120px;">
<td width="170 px" style="text-align: right; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">
</tr>
<tr id="107.117.109.97.114" style="background-color: rgb(232, 232, 232);">
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Which element do you want to select?

Comment: i want to select a complete row for deletion

Answer (score 0):

You can select the rows for example by using CSS-selectors like :

```
#SlotTable > tr:nth-child(1)

#SlotTable > tr:nth-child(2)
```

Comment: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table#SlotTable tr:nth-child(1)")).click();                                                   above line i am using for accessing first row but getting exception

Answer (score 0):

The style of the  elements seem to be the same, so you could use them as identifier and select all elements with that particular style and then do your actions on those.

Comment: i want to select complete row in single go

Answer (score 0):

Try to get row using xpath:

```
//tbody[@id='tableBody']//tr[1]

//tbody[@id='tableBody']/script/tr[1]
```

Change number to access the row you need.

Answer (score 0):

Put this method you will get list of all the ids of rows and you can perform all the activity after that using their id's :

```
public ArrayList<String> ListOfIdsOfRows()
{
   WebElement table =driver.findElement(By.id("SlotTable"));
   WebElement tbody=table.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));
   List<WebElement> rows=tbody.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
   ArrayList<String> ListOdIds=new ArrayList<>();

   for(int i=0;i<rows.size();i++)
   {
     WebElement row = tbody.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='SlotTable']/tbody/tr["+(i+1)+"]"));
     String rowId=row.getAttribute("id");
     ListOdIds.add(rowId);
   }

   return ListOdIds;
}
```